# How to get more Salvaged Frigate Modules?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've been playing through No Man's Sky, and have upgraded almost everything as much as possible, but I'm having trouble gaining the "Salvaged Frigate Modules" (SFM) required to upgrade my freighter.  I'm picking that in the 115+ hrs on this save I may have received maybe 15 total?  And I haven't received any in the past couple weeks.

I've [read](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Salvaged_Frigate_Module) that you can get them through Frigate expeditions, so I'm sending my frigates out on all 5 available expeditions every day, usually 4- or 5- star fleets going out on every expedition (even on the 1-star quick ones), but I rarely get any SFMs in the rewards.  (as an aside, I also never see expeditions higher than 3-star, so maybe if I was seeing 4- or 5-star expeditions there might be more in the rewards, but I don't know)

I have also never found any at Crashed Freighter sites, nor from attacking fleets, and I think I may have received 1 or 2 on a Nexus mission.

Is there a quicker, better, way of getting these?  I only need a handful more to finish upgrading my freighter, but this is getting frustrating!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, your wiki source states all possible methods of receiving the SFMs.

Continuing your search on freighters and supply pods would potentially speed up the process; it seems like you are a victim of bad luck.

Answer (score 2):

[image: .]

Small chances in any of the ways of getting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy the pods attached to frigates without losing reputation.  The cargo pods accompanying the fleet that are not attached to anything will cause you to lose standing when destroyed.  Just don't shoot any of the sentinel ships that spawn in so you only have to put up with 1 enemy, the damage they do is minimal and they're easy to escape from.  Still takes some time but if you do some system hopping you can come across fleets fairly quickly.

However, if you go to a wealthy Gek system you will have better odds of finding such a freighter. Repeatedly save and reload the game whilst there to force it to update to spawn in potential target vessels.